# How to multiply two attributes in same model and get it into another attribute

Tags: java, spring-boot, model, entity

I want to add two numbers in the same entity. Is this correct or how to do it.

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Product {
@Id
private Integer productId;
private String productName;
private Integer noOfUnits;
private Double cartonPrice;
@Transient
private Double unitPrice=cartonPrice-noOfUnits;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No this is not the right way to handle it! You should do all these in service classes based on in which controller this unitPrice field need to be calculated and save it in the database.

Comment: I don't need to save it in the database. I just need the value

Comment: Then Create a class called UnitPriceCalc and then do unitPrice calculation in that class by creating a method and pass the Product Object to it where you can set the calculated unitPrice in that method and return the updated object. Use that class whenever you need the unit price.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Product {
@Id
@Column(name = "product_id")
private Integer productId;
@Column(name = "product_name")
private String productName;
@Column(name = "no_of_units")
private Double noOfUnits;
@Column(name = "carton_price")
private Double cartonPrice;
@Formula("carton_price + no_of_units")
private Double unitPrice;
}
```

Using this can do this calculation.